Unable to Connect to VirtualBox Guest OS (Rocky Linux 8) from Host (Windows 11) Terminal and No Internet Connectivity
I am currently using Oracle VirtualBox
7 with Windows 11 as the host OS. Within VirtualBox, I have Rocky Linux 8 installed as a guest OS. Initially, I had configured the network settings to bridge mode, allowing me to connect to the VirtualBox Linux OS from the Windows terminal. However, recently I have encountered issues where I am unable to connect to the VirtualBox guest OS from the host terminal, and furthermore, the guest OS itself does not have internet connectivity.
I have tried troubleshooting by checking the network settings within VirtualBox, ensuring that the bridge mode is still selected. I have also restarted both the host and guest OS to see if that resolves the issue, but to no avail.
Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve these connectivity issues? I would like to be able to connect to the VirtualBox guest OS from the host terminal and restore internet connectivity to the guest OS. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
